# Creating a Generic Form in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, generics, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a user model with attributes(not all required) first_name, last_name, birthday, profession, pet_name.

for registration the user needs to enter first_name and birthday.

I want to somehow get the attributes which are nil (in this case - last_name and profession) and randomly pick one of them and make a form asking the user to fill it in.

if I do `@user.attributes.map{|k,v| v==nil ? k : nil}.compact` I can get the attributes which are nil.

How do I make a form generic enough so that this method can be used on any attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fill @field in the controller action for displaying form for additional field and then display a form for that field:

```
# controller action
def additional_form
  @field = @user.attributes.select{|k,v| v.nil?}.keys.sample

  if request.post?
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) and redirect_to root_path
  end
end

# view for this action (additional_form.html.erb)
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field @field %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is the "request.post?" part?

Comment: You can do anything you want to save new attribute in controller's action. I just posted this as an example. The behavior is that when form got posted, @user record will be updated with filled attributes and then user will be redirected to the root path.

Comment: Yep, @Hck nailed it. You could also do: `@user.attributes.reject{|k,v| v}.keys.sample` - this will filter keys that are false rather than `nil`, but that shouldn't matter in your case.